# Google file picker Recent tab

Tags: google-docs, google-picker

I got a Google drive picker item on my web app. Looking at Google Docs I find out the it display one option tab called "Recent".

Following the documentation at https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference I couldn't find any reference to this tab mode, only found "Recently Picked" for files I recently picked from the picker, but I'm looking to emulate this function.

My current code is

```
new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)
        .setAppId(appId)
        .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
        .addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true).setOwnedByMe(true))
        .addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true).setOwnedByMe(false))
        .addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setStarred(true).setLabel('Starred'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally after reading the documentation of Google picker and the google groups dedicated to it, I figured out that there is no preset or config for recent uploaded files and even trying to build a custom view with google.picker.view, the query field is quite limited and didn't allow the option to sort the files.

After reading the javascript code of docs.google.com for the file picker I found few variables that are accessible in the moment when you call the method .addView(). This field are:

1. El: is the filter type for the document type.
2. mc: this old the whole view configuration and fields. Example: mc.query is equivalent for the View.setQuery.
3. xd: this field manage the View title in the top nav tab title.

While this method is a bit hacky, is the only option I got in the meantime to replicate the "recent" view tab from google docs. Here is the code I used:

```
let recentView = new google.picker.DocsView();

recentView.xd = 'Recent';
recentView.mc.sortKey = 15;

let picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)
.setAppId(appId)
.setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
.addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true).setOwnedByMe(true))
.addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true).setOwnedByMe(false))
.addView(new google.picker.DocsView().setIncludeFolders(true).setStarred(true).setLabel('Starred'))
.addView(recentView)
.addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setIncludeFolders(true))
.setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
.setCallback(onFilePickerCB)
```

Comment: A new build went out for builder. mc is now Ra. El is now el. xd is now Ca.

Comment: this chnages on every build ....

Comment: money pactching the google apis will not work well with time